# How can I sort the rows of the table for the price ascending and descending upon clicking on the heading "Price"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I created the Product and Store classes, implemented the functions of adding, removing, counting and sorting.
After that, I displayed it all with the help of the HTML table.

Now I need to add to the UI sort by price.

I can sort only once when creating an array. But I do not know how to hang an event that would respond to changing the table and sort it by clicking on the heading of the "Price" column.

```
<div id="_shop">
<form id="addForm">
    <label for="_add_name">Name </label><input id="_add_name"><br/><br/>
    <label for="_price">Price </label><input id="_price"><br/><br/>
    <label for="_count">Count </label><input id="_count"><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add"><br/><br/>
</form>
<form id="removeForm">
    <label for="_del_name">Enter Name </label><input id="_del_name"><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" id="btnDlt" value="Delete"><br/><br/>
</form>

<table id="shopTable">
    <thead>
        <th>Name:</th>
        <th>Price:</th>
        <th>Count:</th>
    </thead>
</table>
```

```
class Product{
    constructor(name, price, count){
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.count = count;
    }

    static get SORT_ORDER_ASC(){
        return 0;
    }

    static get SORT_ORDER_DESC(){
        return 1;
    }
}

class Shop{
    constructor(){
        this.products = [];
    }

    addProduct (product) {
        this.products.push(product);
    };

    deleteProductByName (productName) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
            if (this.products[i].name === productName) {
                this.products.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    };

    get totalProductsPrice () {
        let totalCost = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
            totalCost += this.products[i].count * this.products[i].price;
        }
        return totalCost;
    };

    sortProductsByPrice (sortOrder) {
        let rows = document.querySelectorAll("#shopTable .data");
        for(let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
        {
            //this.products[i].name = rows.item(i).toString();
            console.log(this.products[i].name);
        }

        if(sortOrder === 0) {
            this.products.sort();
            this.products.map(t => t.name + "   " + t.price).join("\n");
        }
        else if(sortOrder === 1) {
            this.products.sort();
            this.products.reverse();
            this.products.map(t => t.name + "   " + t.price).join("\n");
        }
        else {
            console.log("The parameter is incorrect");
        }
    };

    show() {
        let rows = document.querySelectorAll("#shopTable .data");
        let tp = document.querySelectorAll("#totalPrice .data");
        for (let i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            let e = rows.item(i);
            e.parentNode.removeChild(e);

        }
        if(document.getElementById("totalPrice") !== null){
            document.getElementById("totalPrice").remove();
        }
        //tp.parentNode.removeChild(tp);

        let table = document.getElementById("shopTable");
        for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
            table.innerHTML += `<tbody id="tbProducts"><tr class="data">
                                        <td>${this.products[i].name}</td>
                                        <td>${this.products[i].price}</td>
                                        <td>${this.products[i].count}</td>
                                </tr></tbody>`;
        }
        table.innerHTML += `<tfoot><tr><td id="totalPrice">Total price: ${shop.totalProductsPrice}</td></tr></tfoot>`;
    }
}

let shop = new Shop();

shop.addProduct(new Product("product1", 200, 10));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product2", 500, 1));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product3", 1000, 1));
shop.show();

let btnAdd = document.getElementById("btnAdd");
btnAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    shop.addProduct(new Product(document.getElementById('_add_name').value,
                                parseInt(document.getElementById('_price').value),
                                parseInt(document.getElementById('_count').value)));
    //let tmpTotalPrice =
    document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = shop.totalProductsPrice;
    shop.show();
}, false);

let btnDlt = document.getElementById("btnDlt");
btnDlt.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    shop.deleteProductByName(document.getElementById('_del_name').value);
    shop.show();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand your question you can give your `th` an id and add an event listener just as you did for the buttons:

```
<th id="priceHeader">Price:</th>

let priceHeader = document.getElementById("priceHeader");
btnDlt.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    //do your sorting here
});
```

**Edit:**

I made a jsFiddle where I fixed your sort function and added a resort function to your shop class, check if it's what you wanted:

http://jsfiddle.net/2mza4710/24/

new resort function:

```
resort(){
  let sortOrder = this.currentSortOrder === Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC ? Product.SORT_ORDER_DESC : Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC;
  this.currentSortOrder = sortOrder;
  this.sortProductsByPrice(sortOrder);
  this.show();
}
```

change in your sortProductsByPrice function:

```
if(sortOrder === 0) {
  this.products.sort(function(a, b){return a.price - b.price});
}
else if(sortOrder === 1) {
  this.products.sort(function(a, b){return b.price - a.price});
}
```

Comment: do you mean something like that? `let priceHeader = document.getElementById("priceHeader");
    priceHeader .addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        shop.sortProductsByPrice(Product.SORT_ORDER_DESC);
        shop.show();
    }, false);`  but the code only works once, after adding or deleting items does not work

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I need. Thank you very much!

Comment: @senjust Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)